# Strange behavior for ifstream when using an if statement inside a for loop

Tags: c++, input, iostream, ifstream, file-handling

I am working on a game and to establish persistent objects I am calling a function for each object that outputs its current state to a file to be read back in after a new instance of the game is called.

here is what the save file holds for reference:

> "
>   T
>   1
>   10
>   5
>   1
>   5
>   1
>   0
>   0
>   0
>   1
>   15
>   h
>   N
>   0
>   ~
>   S
>   2
>   10
>   6
>   2
>   6
>   2
>   0
>   0
>   0
>   2
>   15
>   h
>   N
>   0
>   ~
>   "

the spaces are actually '\n' chars but for readability I condensed it

now this is just information needed to recreate an instance of class "T" with its previous data. here is my code for restoring

```
for (int i = 0; i < previousActiveCount; i++) {

            file >> typeToRestore;
            if (typeToRestore == 'T') {
                  T* to_restore = new T();
                  T->restore(file, this);
               //calls the restore function for the object of type T which has takes file by reference and then takes input from there
              } else if (typeToRestore == 'S'){
                 S* to_restore = new S();
                 S->restore(file, this); 
                }
}
```

now the issue that arises is that when restore is called inside the objects (with the file passed by reference) the file is not being read right. It is not moving forward in the file. after the if clause its completed, the file never goes from the 'T 1 ... ~' chars to the 'S 2 ...~ ' if I do file >> var; for all the parameters for T inside the if statement they are all acquired from the file. If I cout from the restore function (inherited from the same Base Class) the variables are not set from the file.

here is a sample restore function 'S::restore(file&);

```
if (file.is_open()) {
    int fileID;
    double fileSize;
    double destination_x;
    double destination_y;
    double location_x;
    double location_y;
    double delta_x;
    double delta_y;
    int fileReefID;
    int fileHomeId;
    double fileEnergy;
    double fileState;
    int targetID;
    double fileRange;
    int fileAttack_strength;
    char endFlag;
    file >> fileID;
    file >> fileSize;
    file >> destination_x;
    file >> destination_y;
    file >> location_x;
    file >> location_y;
    file >> delta_x;
    file >> delta_y;
    file >> fileReefID;
    file >> fileHomeId;
    file >> fileEnergy;
    file >> fileState;
    file >> targetID;
    file >> fileRange;
    file >> fileAttack_strength;
    file >> endFlag;
    //do restore procedures
   }
```

none of the variables are being set in this function. Could it be that I'm passing an ifstream instance way too much?

the hierarchy is

-**function1**

- creates an Ifstream object
- calls a restore game function inside a class (Model) and passes this file by reference
- closes the ifstream file.
- **Model's restore function**
- gets the input from the file made in function 1.
- creates a default instance of whatever class the first char identifies
- calls that default class' restore function.
- **default class restore function**
- gets input in sequence with what is saved.
- sets data fields accordingly
- if a value is not valid, throws an exception.

All in all the behavior that this instance is giving me is very puzzling, I am sure that I am only closing the file after it has exited the function chain described above. I am also checking if it is open before getting input. if I don't go into the third function it is fine and all of the input works but as soon as I do an if statement and send off file input to the default class restore function the input is not what it is supposed to be from the file.